# Zend - how to show "page loading" text while waiting for controller function to complete

Tags: zend-framework

I have a data-intensive function, which takes a long time to load.....meaning that when it is called, it shows a blank screen for a while until the data processing finally completes. The only way I know to display text right now is thru the .phtml files that load *after* the controller function completes.

I'm wondering if it's possible to insert some kind of gif or text telling the user "page loading....please be patient" or something to that effect.....just so they know to keep waiting, and that the function isn't just hanging.

I'm using Zend framework 1, but I'd be interested in knowing a solution even if it only applies to later versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing build-in.

There are multiple solutions:

- using PHP-FPM, look at how [Symfony kernel.terminate event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-terminate) works (look at the code), and that's a solution
- using a queuing system, send a job in the queue when serving the controller, and display your `please wait` message. Get feedback from the queue and refresh the page when ready.

Comment: Can anyone please help implementing this?